# Plot with multiple axes (via add_axes) within pyplot's subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a piece of code that successfully creates a grid of subplots via pyplot.subplots. I add data to and manipulate each of these subplots by interacting with the axis returned by subplots. For example:

```
fig, axis = plt.subplots(n,m)
axis[x,y].plot(some_data)
```

I also have a piece of code to create a rather complex plot with three axis via add_axes, for example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes(position1)
ax2 = fig.add_axes(position2)
ax3 = fig.add_axes(position3)
ax1.plot(some_data)
ax2.plot(some_other_data_derived_from_some_data)
ax3.plot(some_other_data_derived_from_some_data)
```

This second piece of code to create the chart with three axis can be called as a function/module.

What I would like to do, ideally, is to modify my first code to insert within each subplot (axis[x,y]) a plot created via the second piece of code (with all three axis). This is sort of using a template for each subplot.

I know this might be a bit messy, but it would be easier to implement that having to re-write the first piece of code to create a gird of plots with the three axis (for that I would probably have to create even more subplots, make them share axis, close the gaps between them, etc).

Is there a way to plot within each subplot a plot with the three axis as created by the second piece of code? Could I "call" the second piece of code and have it return a figure that I can insert in the subplot? Or could I call the code passing the data, figure and subplot-axis and make it plot within the subplot the three axis?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wow, four days and not even a suggestion?! Could someone please tell me, is it a very hard or a very dumb question?